# limiting length of elements in div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="fcb_pt_1-1" maxlength="5" >

    <span id="fcb_pt_yt1"> 1<input type="button" value="Remove" id="fcb_pt_yt1-1" /></span><br>

    <span id="fcb_pt_yt2"> 2<input type="button" value="Remove" id="fcb_pt_yt2-1" /></span><br>

    <span id="fcb_pt_yt3"> 3<input type="button" value="Remove" id="fcb_pt_yt3-1" /></span><br> 

    <span id="fcb_pt_yt4"> 4<input type="button" value="Remove" id="fcb_pt_yt4-1"/></span><br>

    <span id="fcb_pt_yt5"> 5<input type="button" value="Remove" id="fcb_pt_yt5-1" /></span><br>

    <span id="fcb_pt_yt6"> 6<input type="button" value="Remove" id="fcb_pt_yt6-1"/></span><br>

    <span id="fcb_pt_yt7"> 7<input type="button" value="Remove" id="fcb_pt_yt7-1"/></span><br>

   <span id="fcb_pt_yt8"> 8<input type="button" value="Remove" id="fcb_pt_yt8-1" /></span><br>

   <span id="fcb_pt_yt9"> 9<input type="button" value="Remove" id="fcb_pt_yt9-1" /></span><br>

   <span id="fcb_pt_yt10"> 10<input type="button" value="Remove" id="fcb_pt_yt10-1"/></span><br>
```

```
   <span id="fcb_pt_t1-1"><input type="button" value="Select" id="fcb_pt_t1" /> 1</span>    <br>

   <span id="fcb_pt_t2-1"><input type="button" value="Select" id="fcb_pt_t2"/> 2</span> <br>

   <span id="fcb_pt_t3-1"><input type="button" value="Select" id="fcb_pt_t3" /> 3</span> <br>

   <span id="fcb_pt_t4-1"><input type="button" value="Select" id="fcb_pt_t4"/> 4</span> <br>

   <span id="fcb_pt_t5-1"><input type="button" value="Select" id="fcb_pt_t5"/> 5 </span><br>

   <span id="fcb_pt_t6-1"><input type="button" value="Select" id="fcb_pt_t6"/> 6</span><br>

   <span id="fcb_pt_t7-1"><input type="button" value="Select" id="fcb_pt_t7"/> 7</span><br>

   <span id="fcb_pt_t8-1"><input type="button" value="Select" id="fcb_pt_t8"/> 8 </span><br>

   <span id="fcb_pt_t9-1"><input type="button" value="Select" id="fcb_pt_t9"/> 9</span><br>

   <span id="fcb_pt_t10-1"><input type="button" value="Select" id="fcb_pt_t10"/> 10 </span><br>
```

CSS:

```
   #fcb_pt_1-1 {visibility: hidden;}    
     .your_team { visibility: visible;}
```

**These are my two div with elements in it. The elements in first div are hidden. When I click the button on second div, the element or span of the first div appears. The jquery written for it is this,**

```
$('#fcb_pt_t1').click(function(){ 
     $('#fcb_pt_t1-1').hide(); 
     $('#fcb_pt_yt1').addClass('your_team').show();
      });

   $('#fcb_pt_yt1-1').click(function(){     
      $('#fcb_pt_yt1').hide(); 
      $('#fcb_pt_t1-1').show();
            });



     $('#fcb_pt_t2').click(function(){ 
     $('#fcb_pt_t2-1').hide(); 
     $('#fcb_pt_yt2').addClass('your_team').show();
      });

   $('#fcb_pt_yt2-1').click(function(){     
      $('#fcb_pt_yt2').hide(); 
      $('#fcb_pt_t2-1').show();
            });




$('#fcb_pt_t3').click(function(){ 
     $('#fcb_pt_t3-1').hide(); 
     $('#fcb_pt_yt3').addClass('your_team').show();
      });

   $('#fcb_pt_yt3-1').click(function(){     
      $('#fcb_pt_yt3').hide(); 
      $('#fcb_pt_t3-1').show();
            });



$('#fcb_pt_t4').click(function(){ 
     $('#fcb_pt_t4-1').hide(); 
     $('#fcb_pt_yt4').addClass('your_team').show();
      });

   $('#fcb_pt_yt4-1').click(function(){     
      $('#fcb_pt_yt4').hide(); 
      $('#fcb_pt_t4-1').show();
            });



$('#fcb_pt_t5').click(function(){ 
     $('#fcb_pt_t5-1').hide(); 
     $('#fcb_pt_yt5').addClass('your_team').show();
      });

   $('#fcb_pt_yt5-1').click(function(){     
      $('#fcb_pt_yt5').hide(); 
      $('#fcb_pt_t5-1').show();
            });



$('#fcb_pt_t6').click(function(){ 
     $('#fcb_pt_t6-1').hide(); 
     $('#fcb_pt_yt6').addClass('your_team').show();
      });

   $('#fcb_pt_yt6-1').click(function(){     
      $('#fcb_pt_yt6').hide(); 
      $('#fcb_pt_t6-1').show();
            });




$('#fcb_pt_t7').click(function(){ 
     $('#fcb_pt_t7-1').hide(); 
     $('#fcb_pt_yt7').addClass('your_team').show();
      });

   $('#fcb_pt_yt7-1').click(function(){     
      $('#fcb_pt_yt7').hide(); 
      $('#fcb_pt_t7-1').show();
            });



$('#fcb_pt_t8').click(function(){ 
     $('#fcb_pt_t8-1').hide(); 
     $('#fcb_pt_yt8').addClass('your_team').show();
      });

   $('#fcb_pt_yt8-1').click(function(){     
      $('#fcb_pt_yt8').hide(); 
      $('#fcb_pt_t8-1').show();
            });


$('#fcb_pt_t9').click(function(){ 
     $('#fcb_pt_t9-1').hide(); 
     $('#fcb_pt_yt9').addClass('your_team').show();
      });

   $('#fcb_pt_yt9-1').click(function(){     
      $('#fcb_pt_yt9').hide(); 
      $('#fcb_pt_t9-1').show();
            });




$('#fcb_pt_t10').click(function(){ 
     $('#fcb_pt_t10-1').hide(); 
     $('#fcb_pt_yt10').addClass('your_team').show();
      });

   $('#fcb_pt_yt10-1').click(function(){     
      $('#fcb_pt_yt10').hide(); 
      $('#fcb_pt_t10-1').show();
            });
```

**This is the jquery written for selecting and hiding the elements. What I want to do is, restrict the length of the elements to select. Since there are 10 elements in the second div, I should only be able to select only any 5 elements that should show in the second div.
If the question is unclear, I can edit and be more specific. Thank you.**

Comment: can you please post a Fiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=9IaLoypzh9

Comment: Doesn't make for a particularly good UX. Drag-and-drop works well for this kind of app.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you should do some refactoring utilizing the this keyword to not have to repeat code so much.

Second, refactor your click events so you track the selected ids in an array. Add to and remove from the array as you select the elements. Then if the length is > limit then don't actually select that element.

Comment: i wish i could, i'm new to this, what i could do, i did that. I'm learning, but was unable to do the method you suggested, i already tried that, but couldn't get an ouput, so i did like this.